# Why in vulkan.h non dispatchable objects are always typedefed to 64bit?

Tags: c, vulkan

Looking into the vulkan.h i see this:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__x86_64__) || .....
    #define VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object) typedef struct object##_T *object;
#else
    #define VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object) typedef uint64_t object;
#endif
```

Does anyone has an idea why the 64bits? For me it appears more reasonable to always use the first case of the ifdef

Comment: "Always"? - According to the code shown, they are not. But what size would a pointer have on a non-64 bit platform? And what size does it have on the platforms used for the first cases?

Comment: My question was based on the assumption that a 64bit platform has 64bit pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [spec it explicitly says](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#fundamentals-objectmodel-overview) that the non-dispatchable handles must be 64 bits:

> Non-dispatchable handle types are a 64-bit integer type whose meaning
>   is implementation-dependent, and may encode object information
>   directly in the handle rather than pointing to a software structure.
>   Objects of a non-dispatchable type may not have unique handle values
>   within a type or across types. If handle values are not unique, then
>   destroying one such handle must not cause identical handles of other
>   types to become invalid, and must not cause identical handles of the
>   same type to become invalid if that handle value has been created more
>   times than it has been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It was simpler and more obvious than I thought.

Comment: If that's the case, then why are the handles defined as pointers on 64-bit architecture, rather than as uint64_t's? After reading that paragraph, it seems to me more reasonable to always use the second part of the #ifdef.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson probably because C and C++ don't have strong typedefs so they use the pointer to help type-safety.