# What does VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE mean

Tags: c++, vulkan

I understand that `VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE` is either a `struct object##_T *object` or `uint64_t object` depending on the architecture.

What I **don't** understand is why this is used and what benefits and/or effect it has.

For example, if I want to get the `pCode` from my `VkShaderModule` why am I not able to just go `myShaderModule.pCode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In many areas the Vulkan API implements opaque handles. In essence this means that the implementer can do pretty much whatever they like and is not bound by any contract to the client in terms of memory layout of the object or even the handle being a real pointer.

If you want to get the `pCode` from your `VkShaderModule` I suggest that you store it yourself when you create it rather than relying on the implementation to store it for you.

The intention of Vulkan was to remove the burden from the graphics API and remove bloat.  Storing user provided data and providing an API to get said user data is bloat. If you want to keep such things, make a map of `VkShaderModules` to whichever parameters you want to keep from `VkShaderModuleCreateInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense with the overall theme behind Vulkan API

Comment: `glGetShaderSource` is the OpenGL equivalent of what you are asking really. It's a pointless function call really. If the client needs this information they can just store it themselves as they provided it in the first place! In practice it ends up being a waste of memory that every single graphics application in the system incurs as the driver has to store these strings. There was a lot of nonsense like this in GL and it was removed from Vulkan.

Answer (score 4):

> What does VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE mean?

According to conversation [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35582314/560648), the key points here are:

1. A handle type must be 64 bits in size
2. A handle type should be unique, where possible

On a 64-bit platform, you can make use of pointers being 64-bit to create lots of different, unique types; thus your handle types can't be interchanged.

Otherwise, the best you can do is `uint64_t`, which isn't *quite* as type-safe.

In C++11 we'd probably go with `enum class handle##_t : uint64_t {}` to get the best of both worlds.

---

> For example, if I want to get the pCode from my VkShaderModule why am I not able to just go myShaderModule.pCode?

Dunno what this means, sorry.

Comment: Non-dispatchable handles in Vulkan are not required to be unique. This allows the implementation to directly store all of the info about the object in the handle itself (might be useful for VkSampler, for example), rather than allocating a separate object.

Comment: @JesseHall: Didn't say they were.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: "*A handle should be unique, where possible*" That sounds like handles should be unique.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `assert(strcmp("should be", "are required to be") != 0);` However, I did actually mean to say "a handle _type_ should be unique"; the next sentence in my answer explains why you may want them to be... and why `VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE` is defined this way. Apparently I was mistaken but that's what I thought the OP (who seems to have accepted an unrelated answer) was asking.

Comment: @JesseHall Could you explain what it means "This allows the implementation to directly store all of the info about the object in the handle itself" . I read it already second time (first one in specs) and I don't actually understand what that means. Props are encoded into the handle as bitflags? Or as values in different bitfields?

Comment: @MichaelIV I never said such a thing, but I assume it means that such a "handle" may be intended to be treated as a pointer to some data elsewhere, _or_ it can actually be intended to just be used as a value outright. It's an integer so in practice it can be treated as both. It's up to the person who creates the handle to document how it can be used. Generally if the information that's being "handled" is 64 bits or smaller, and doesn't need to be shared, then you can just set the handle itself to that value and be done with it

Answer (score 2):

Section "3.3. Object Model" of the Vulkan specification describes both types of handles.

https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap3.html#fundamentals-objectmodel-overview

Dispatchable handle is a pointer to an object in memory. Although opaque on the client side, implementation can dereference it. It's unique by definition. Non-dispatchable handle, even if cast to a pointer type, is a numeric handle that you can't dereference, and is valid only in a context. Numeric handles have some advantages over pointers: they are safer, because the pointer is not exposed, they are flexible and may be just indices or enums, and they allow the underlying object to be relocated in memory.